# Can `new` and `delete` be used in a DriverKit driver?

Tags: c++, macos-catalina, driverkit, macos-system-extension

DriverKit provides [`IONewZero`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ionewzero?language=objc) and [`IOSafeDeleteNULL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/iosafedeletenull?language=objc). Those does not call any constructor or destructor.

Let's say that I would like to have some class in the ivars structure. The class does not need to inherit from `OSObject` nor `IOService`. How should I construct this object? If I have it as a member in the `ivars` struct the constructor of my class is not called. If I keep a pointer to my class in the ivars structure I need to allocate and call the constructor of the class. Can I use `new` / `delete` for this?

Comment: "_There are no alignment guarantees on the returned memory_" looks scary. Perhaps [`OSTypeAlloc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ostypealloc?language=objc) is a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `operator new` is indeed implemented in the DriverKit runtime. I've used it successfully to allocate and initialise my `…_IVars` objects themselves. (the PIMPL type that's automatically forward-declared by the header generated by `iig` for any classes defined in  `.iig` files)

So, I actually do this in `MyDriver::init()`:

```
    this->ivars = new MyDriver_IVars();
```

and then in `MyDriver::free()`:

```
    if (this->ivars != nullptr)
    {
        // … some extra cleanup …

        delete this->ivars;
        this->ivars = nullptr;
    }
```

In my opinion this is about the cleanest approach achievable given the constraints forced upon us by the `iig` system.

I strongly suspect `operator new` is implemented with the same back-end as in regular macOS user space, though I've not actually gone and checked yet as I've not encountered any issues with it at all so far. Obviously, the corresponding `delete` works too.

`OSTypeAlloc` is for `OSObject`-derived types and should definitely be used for those, but won't work for other types.

Comment: Evidence I found, Apple doesn't want us to use new even though it is usable. I would strongly disagree using new/delete. Instead have a look in the available choices - [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/memory_utilities)